# How to skip devise user authentication in rails mountable engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I created a mountable engine to expose JSON API to frontend app and it is plugged to existing Rails 4.2 app which is fully authenticated by `devise` gem.

But for API, I created a token based authentication, that means devise authentication is no more required in API controllers.

I am trying to skip devise authentication for API controllers as follows but nothings seems working. I always get `401` response `You need to sign in`.

*In the API's parent controller* **(frontend/ApplicationController.rb)**:

```
skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!  # OR skip_before_action :authenticate_user!
```

*And I tried providing `unuthencated` routes (in **routes.rb** file),*

```
unauthenticated do
  mount frontend, at: '/frontend'
end
```

Source: [devise docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Define-resource-actions-that-require-authentication-using-routes.rb)

Can anyone help me how to do this? Are there any other approaches?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try to ad that in controller under `skip_before_filter :authent...` => `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:your_action] `

Comment: @RonanLouarn - No luck. But I made it work by renaming `ApplicationController` to `ApiApplicationController` or something in the engine. So it is no relate to parent app `ApplicationController` and it skips authentication. I have a feeling that it's a dirty fix but it works fine for me.